# What is the best algorithm to differentiate these kidney pictures?

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, medical-imaging

I work on medical images of kidneys scans.
My goal would be to differentiate normal ones from pathologic ones (**binary problem**).
Normal images have regular bilateral kidney contours, whereas abnormal cases can be patchy with foci of decreased intensity or defects.

Here are examples :

- [Normal kidney scan, with regular bilateral kidney contours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLWas.jpg)
- [Pathologic right kidney, with irregular contours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCBP5.png)

I tried to train a **convolutional neural network** to differentiate normal and pathologic scans.
I have 824 images for my training set (552 normal, 272 pathologic).

The best results I get is by pre-treating images like this :

- Cropping to have, from 1 picture, 2 pictures of unique kidney
- Flipping right kidneys to only have "left" kidneys
- Gaussian filter to limit noise and smooth the contours
- Otsu threshold to binarise my pictures.

This is the kind of pictures I get after this :

- [Example of normal kidney (treated)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnWRO.png)
- [Example of pathological kidney (treated)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUuNl.png)

Unfortunately, the best results I get in validation is like ~ 85 % of accuracy.
I'd like to reach at least 90-95 %.

Here is my code, with tensorflow :

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape = [x_train.shape[1], x_train.shape[2], x_train.shape[3]]))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=2, padding='valid'))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=2, padding='valid'))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=2, padding='valid'))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(units = 16, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(units = 1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

es = EarlyStopping(monitor = 'val_accuracy', mode = 'max', verbose = 1, patience = 6)
mc = ModelCheckpoint('best_model.h5', monitor='val_accuracy', mode='max', verbose=1, save_best_only=True)

history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=50, batch_size=128, verbose=1, validation_split=0.3, callbacks = [es, mc])
```

I get more or less the same results when I change number layers, of neurons by layer (from 16 to 128), dropout between each layer, batch size etc...

So I'm wondering if I am using the good method.
I also tried anomaly detection algorithm with autoencoders but the pictures seemed to close to get appropriate detection...

So my question is :

- Do you see something I could do to **improve my CNN algorithm** ?
- Do you know **another algorithm** I should try ? Like a one that would be good on **detection of irregular contours** ?

Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: While certainly interesting, your question is way too broad for SO, please focus on a single explicit question. Recommendations for libraries (or algorithms) and code review are off topic (check https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for the latter)

Comment: Hi! You should try Data augmentation too through ImageGenerator because of limited dataset size for training.  https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator . If you are using a pair of kidney images in Dataset , you should label those pairs as unhealthy even if they contain a single pathologically treated kidney.